# What happens if I don't preface data attributes with "data-"?

Tags: html, custom-data-attribute

I frequently end up storing data in DOM elements and make heavy use of custom data attributes and  JQuery.  I know the HTML5 spec says data attributes should have the `data-` prefix, but as far as I can tell there's no harm in naming my attributes whatever I want.

Problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only problem is in validation. Non-standard element attributes are not valid HTML5. So, there is no **harm** in them, but the danger of operating outside of any spec is that it may not be supported in the future or by a specific user-agent. You also run the risk that in the future, the spec will *include* your non-standard attribute, but it will mean something else entirely than what you intended. Worse case scenario, you have to go update the page when a new feature of the spec is implemented.

In the case of element attributes, it *should* work in all browsers.

Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536429%28VS.85%29.aspx for info on this subject as it pertains to Internet Explorer.

Comment: Well thought out and well put.  Thank you.  I think I can live with the risks, HTML standards do not move at breakneck speeds.

Answer (score 1):

If you're OK with invalid HTML, then there's no problem. People have been doing it your way for years, so it's unlikely that any browsers will break the behavior you expect.