# HTML5 Data Attributes Unique Name?

Tags: html

What are your thoughts on making HTML5 *data attributes* unique. Aren't there plenty of JavaScript plugins out there now that are actively looking for *data attributes* for their script to work. In a practical case they wouldn't fire unless a parent had a class Id assume, however I am sure there is one out there that doesn't? So is it **safe** to use ...

```
<!-- The script therfore looking for the class kmgilbert-cfs to fire -->
<div class="kmgilbert-cfs">
  <div
    id="randomid"
    data-title="1"
    data-description="A Demo Description Here"
    data-responsive="true">
  </div>
</div>
```

Or would it be more wise to use the following with unique data attribute names

```
<!-- The script therfore looking for the class kmgilbert-cfs to fire -->
<div class="kmgilbert-cfs">
  <div
    id="randomid"
    data-cfs-title="1"
    data-cfs-description="A Demo Description Here"
    data-cfs-responsive="true">
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance hopefully this will help clear this up for me!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What happens if I don't preface data attributes with "data-"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7111798/what-happens-if-i-dont-preface-data-attributes-with-data)

Comment: Thanks for that! I removed the first question I had and left the second one.

Comment: The uniqueness of your attribute keys is probably only relevant when you're using them as element selectors. If you're not targeting data attributes with CSS, jQuery, etc., it just doesn't matter.